# Implement SSH command to return a contents of a file in Apache Mina

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, apache-mina

I have created an SSH server which is opening `cmd`. When I connect with Putty `cmd` is open and for example, if I write `dir` (which is the command that I put in the code) everything is okay.

Now, my question is: How to create some API (for example if i write: `hello` like a command) to return some file content.

I want to achieve this:
 1. Connect with Putty to the server
 2. write "hello" for example
 3. print in putty console content of some file.

Here is the code for my SSH server. I am using apache-mina library:

public class SshServerMock {

```
public static void server() throws IOException, JSchException, SftpException {
    SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();

    sshd.setHost("127.0.0.1");
    sshd.setPort(22);

    sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("C://hostkey.ser")));
    sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(new PasswordAuthenticator() {

        @Override
        public boolean authenticate(String u, String p, ServerSession s) {              
            return ("root".equals(u) && "iskratel".equals(p));
        }   

    });

    sshd.setShellFactory(new ProcessShellFactory(new String[] { "cmd.exe" }));
    sshd.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100000000000l);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: This is too vague. It's not clear if you want to keep the "shell" functionality and add a new "shell" command "hello". Or if you just want to provide some kind of API to return a contents of a file. You should explain your use case, rather than just your imagined implementation.

Comment: It need to return contents of a file. Sorry for the bad explaining.

Comment: Edit your question!

Comment: I`ve edited it. Btw the documentation is so low and what I found that maybe is correct it says that i need to create some list of commands that will be accepted... But i have now idea how to make it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By executing `cmd`, you start a Windows shell. At that moment the session gets out of control of your code. You cannot add a command to the shell using your Java code.

But obviously, you can add the command in the Windows shell. Just create a `hello.bat` batch file and make sure it's in Windows `PATH` for an easy access. Make sure the `PATH` is set for the local ("local" as of the server) account that runs the session.

The `hello.bat` batch file can be as trivial as:

```
type c:\path\to\file.txt
```

---

Note that allowing an user to run `cmd.exe` can be pretty dangerous. So make sure you know, what you are doing.

---

In my opinion, you should implement the `CommandFactory` interface.

Make it create a `Command` that feed the "file" to the stream provided by `setOutputStream`.

On client side, with JSch library, use this code:
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html